# Books about manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, self-learning

I would like to learn about manifolds. Please can someone recommend me a good book to learn about manifolds?

Comment: Any kind of manifolds in particular (e.g. smooth)? What's your mathematical background?

Comment: [Loring Tu](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10588121-an-introduction-to-manifolds)  has written a wonderful, reader friendly introduction to manifolds. His book is one of  the most pedagogical books, not only in differential geometry but  in all of mathematics, that  I have ever seen.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis My background is with linear algebra, real analysis, abstract algebra and topology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like

> **Introduction to Smooth Manifolds** by *John M. Lee*.

The [wikipedia article on manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) is also quite nice and contains a number of references.

Comment: Yes, Lee's book is very precise, richly illustrated (Geometry *is* a visual science! The Wikipedia article referred to has stupendous drawings by the way) and very complete. It would be optimal to start reading it after having studied Loring Tu for a few months.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you I will try in this order.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to have a complete look at

> **Elementary Differential Geometry** by *Barrett O'Neill*

then

> **Differentiable Manifolds an Introduction** by  *F Brickell & R. S. Clark*.

However it is an old one, I had good times while taking a course studying it before. This is a good one. Also, if you are interested to have a $\color{red}{\text{c}}\color{blue}{\text{o}}\color{green}{\text{l}}\color{brown}{\text{o}}\color{yellow}{\text{r}}ful$ $\color{purple}{\text{nightmare}}$, you may see this complete reference:

> **A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry** by *M. Spivak*.

Comment: Brickell-Clark indeed brings back fond memories to me and is a great book. But why is Spivak colourful (it is in black and white) and above all why is it a nightmare?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Yes it is indeed. I meant it because of its strange figures. :D Indeed, Spivak, has his own island full of strange creatures in mathematical world . I admire him so much.

Comment: Dear @Babak: thanks for your explanation. I also admire Spivak very much.

Comment: @amWhy: If you have had any chances to see this book, you would agree with me. This book has a different taste Amy. :D

Answer (score 1):

Detailed and well explainediscussion about manifolds can be seen in 
Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups by Frank W. Warner.

Answer (score 0):

A widely used and known reference is Kodayashi and Nomizu's [Foundations of differential geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471157333). Another great one is Spivak's  [Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098705). I liked the style of Choquet-Bruhat and De Witt-Morette's [Analysis, Manifolds and Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444860177): it contains examples from classical physics and more.

There are tons of other good books, but these three are the first ones that popped up into my mind :-)

Comment: Dear @Avitus: Kobayashi and Nomizu, two very competent speecialists,  wrote a great, very advanced reference book but I think it is unsuitable for a beginner: no exercises, no elementary calculations, no pictures. I am speaking from experience: this was the first book on the subject I looked at long ago and I understood nothing in it. I only began to understand manifolds by reading [Brickell-Clark](http://www.amazon.com/Differentiable-Manifolds-Introduction-F-Brickell/dp/B000GP5YO6), which is still quite praiseworthy, but now there is Loring Tu, which I think can't be beaten for quality.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Years ago, I had to read K. and N. as a very great references just to prepare for writing a paper. Their works are all considered as articles or papers, however they're published as hard cover books.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: I agree with you. Honestly speaking, to read the KN book was really hard: I used it together with the Choquet-Bruhat to select those information that were relevant at the beginning. I think it is still a great book, though. A friend of mine studied on the Loring Tu, and he was quite happy of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Loring Tu's Introduction to manifolds is a very good book as has been mentioned already. 'An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry' by W.Boothby is another book that you may like to consider.